# .matchedGeometryEffect() not animating view

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

I'm trying to recreate this Photos.app animation using SwiftUI (see gif). When clicking one of the images in the grid, it should expand into full size, and be embedded in a NavigationView. To have some separation of concerns, I wan't it to be two separate views.

[image: Phots open image animation]

### What I have tried

Im using [Swift Composable Architecture](https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-composable-architecture) for handling state, but this should be relevant here.

I have a "root" `GalleryView`, which toggles between showing the grid view and the full screen view, based on if an image is selected or not.

```
struct GalleryView: View {
  let store: Store<AppState, AppAction>
  @Namespace var namespace
  
  var body: some View {
    WithViewStore(self.store) { viewStore in
      if let token = viewStore.selectedToken {
        NavigationView {
          FullscreenView(store: store, namespace: namespace, token: token)
            .navigationTitle(token.name)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Button("Close") {viewStore.send(.dismissImageTapped)})
        }
      } else {
        GridView(store: store, namespace: namespace)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `GridView`:

```
struct GridView: View {
  let store: Store<AppState, AppAction>
  var namespace: Namespace.ID
  
  var body: some View {
    WithViewStore(self.store) { viewStore in
      ZStack {
        VStack {
          ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 150, maximum: 600), spacing: 0)], alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
              ForEach(viewStore.tokens, id: \.id) { token in
                CachedImage(url: URL(string: token.image_url)!) { image in
                  VStack {
                    GeometryReader { gr in
                      image
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: token.id, in: namespace)
                        .frame(width: gr.size.width, height: gr.size.width, alignment: .center)
                    }
                    .clipped()
                    .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
                  }
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                  viewStore.send(.imageTapped(token))
                }
              }
            }
          }
          .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
          .onAppear {
            viewStore.send(.getTokensButtonTapped)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the `FullscreenView`:

```
struct FullscreenView: View {
  let store: Store<AppState, AppAction>
  var namespace: Namespace.ID
  let token: Token
  
  var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
      WithViewStore(self.store) { viewStore in
        if let selectedToken = viewStore.selectedToken {
          CachedImage(url: URL(string: selectedToken.image_url)!) { image in
            GeometryReader { gr in
              image
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: token.id, in: namespace)
            }
          }
          .onTapGesture {
            viewStore.send(.dismissImageTapped)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This produces no animation at all. I have also tried to put the `.matchedGeomtryEffect()` on the `CachedImage` view as well, without any luck.

How can I achieve this? What are some things I have to look out for when using `.matchedGeomtryEffect()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/69734153/12299030? Also next might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/64414233/12299030.

Comment: It might be worth watching the video sessions on Animation with TCA https://www.pointfree.co/collections/swiftui/animations

Comment: Were you able to solve this? What happens if you add withAnimation block after the matchedGeometryEffect?